# Check if point is in proximity of transformed rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, collision-detection, rectangles

I've got a `Rectangle` that is transformed by setting its RenderTransform property to a `TransformGroup`. The transform group contains the following transformations: `SkewTransform`, `RotateTransform`, `TranslateTransform`.

Now I'd like to create a method that determines wether a `Point` is near the rectangle. So not only when the point is *in* the (transformed) rectangle, but also when it is very close to it. Without just using an imaginary circle/radius from the centerpoint of the rectangle.

The treshold that determines wether the point is close enough and can be seen as being in proximity, is always at the same distance from the silhouette of the transformed rectangle. You can see it like the rectangle has a border of, say, 30 pixels. When the point is in this border (or the rectangle itself), the result is *true*. Otherwise the result is *false*.

Having all help of the .NET framework available, it seems easy. It tried several approaches, like using `Visual.pointFromScreen()`. Reversing the transformation, etc. But I keep doing something wrong.

And to make things extra difficult, I am also looking for an efficient solution that is fast.

Code I tried:

```
public bool IsInHitArea(Point pt)
{
    // _transformedRect = my rectangle
    // HitRectangleMargin = proximity treshold.
    // _offsetX, _offsetY = x and y position of rectangle
    // _areaWidth, _areaHeight = width/height of rectangle

    Point p = _transformedRect.PointFromScreen(pt);

    return (p.X >= _offsetX - HitRectangleMargin
        && p.X <= _offsetX + _areaWidth + HitRectangleMargin
        && p.Y >= _offsetY - HitRectangleMargin
        && p.Y <= _offsetY + _areaHeight + HitRectangleMargin);
}

// Or another try

public bool IsInHitArea(Point pt)
{
    // TransformGroup is a property containing the transform group.

    Point p = TransformGroup.Inverse.Transform(pt);

    // I actually don't really undersand if it's maybe naive to use just the following
    // equations:
    return (p.X >= _offsetX - HitRectangleMargin
        && p.X <= _offsetX + _areaWidth + HitRectangleMargin
        && p.Y >= _offsetY - HitRectangleMargin
        && p.Y <= _offsetY + _areaHeight + HitRectangleMargin);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the best code that you tried

Comment: Make an invisible copy of the transformed rectangle, scale it up to match the threshold perimeter, then check if point is inside that rectangle ... that's what I'd do, roughly.

Comment: How exactly is the Rectangle transformed? By its RenderTransform, or do you use a Path with a transformed Geometry as its Data?

Comment: @Clemens By setting the RenderTransform property on the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Rectangle that is transformed by its `RenderTransform`, you might better use a Path with a transformed `RectangleGeometry`.

You could overlay the displayed Path with another one that has a transparent `Stroke` and `Fill` and a wide enough `StrokeThickness` to capture mouse input in the proximity of the displayed rectangle.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Canvas>
    <Path Data="{Binding TransformedRectangle}"
          StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="Black"/>

    <Path Data="{Binding TransformedRectangle}"
          StrokeThickness="60" StrokeLineJoin="Round"
          Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent"
          MouseLeftButtonDown="PathMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
</Canvas>
```

A sample view model that provides the transformed geometry:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public RectangleGeometry TransformedRectangle { get; } = new RectangleGeometry();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var transform = new TransformGroup();
        transform.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(2, 1));
        transform.Children.Add(new SkewTransform(30, 0));
        transform.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(45, 250, 150));

        TransformedRectangle.Rect = new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
        TransformedRectangle.Transform = transform;
    }
}
```